# Stage failing on Jenkins even though the logs says it was successfull

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, javadoc, stage

I have a stage in my Jenkins pipeline to generate and publish the javadoc of my application but for some reason when I run it the build fails because of that stage as it is possible to see in the below screenshot
[image]

When I consult the log to see what's the problem it says that the task was successful
[image]

This is the code in my pipeline for this stage

```
 stage('Generate and publish Javadoc on Windows') {
            when { expression { env.OS == 'BAT' }}
            steps {
                dir('') {
                    bat 'gradlew.bat javadoc'
                    javadoc javadocDir: 'build/docs/javadoc', keepAll: true
                }
            }
        }
```

I think this error could be because there is no new things to publish in the javadoc since my application hasn't changed. Could this be it?

How can I fix this problem?